# How to append 'OPTION (MAXDOP 1)' to SQLAlchemy select statement?

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, sqlalchemy

I am translating queries from raw Transact-SQL to SQLAlchemy (v1.4 with future mode, happy to consider v2 as well).

Some of the queries limit the max degree of parallelism with `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)`.

```sql
SELECT
[...]
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

Is there a way to append this `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` to a SQLAlchemy select without a compiler extension ?